# Showing button two times when i am selecting dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, visual-studio-2008

I have dropdown inside gridview :

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Category">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGrdCategory" CssClass="NormalText" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Width="75%"                             onselectedindexchanged="ItemChange" >
  </asp:DropDownList>
 </ItemTemplate>
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="left" />
```

when i am changing its selection, below grid there is one button (not part of grid), its showing me that button two times when i am changing selection.

Before Selection:

[image]

After Selection:

[image]

Whole Design:

http://pastie.org/8473903

Note button is simply below the grid:

```
<tr>
<td>

...here is grid....
</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnOk" runat="server" Text="Ok" CssClass="ButtonBlack"   />


                        </td>

                        </tr>
```

Comment: @zxc sir, its mentioned in http://pastie.org/8473903 at last, but still <td align="center">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnOk" runat="server" Text="Ok" CssClass="ButtonBlack"   />
                  
                    
                    </td>

Comment: Can you see the C# code that create button so it would be helpful.

Comment: @VaibhavParmar if you see http://pastie.org/8473903 ..button is not created on c#, its simple aspx page button

Comment: Do u have any code in the page load ?

Comment: @ArulDinesh code on page load: http://pastie.org/8473934

Comment: If Button OK Operation is not associated with UPDATE PANEL then remove Button from Update Panel and Add same code after Update Panel.

Comment: @RamdasBhosale will u plz post this thing as a answer? its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlGrd" runat="server" >
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:GridView ID="GrdBarcode" runat="server" 
       AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" Width="100%"
       EmptyDataText="No records found.">
      <Columns>
      </Columns>
      <HeaderStyle CssClass="TableHeadingNormal" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
      <RowStyle CssClass="NormalText" VerticalAlign="Top" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
      <EmptyDataRowStyle CssClass="NormalText" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
             Font-Bold="True" />
      </asp:GridView>
   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<Table>
  <tr>
   <td align="center">
     <asp:Button ID="btnOk" runat="server" Text="Ok" CssClass="ButtonBlack"   />
   </td>
 </tr>
```